# How to display text correctly with streamlit, I have a strange formatting happening

Tags: python, streamlit

[image]

I'm on streamlit in my app but when I diplay some texts, here is what I get and I can't make it clean.

I tried using
`st.markdown(response2,unsafe_allow_html=True)`
but also

```
plain_text = markdown2.markdown(response2, extras=["no-html"])
st.write(plain_text)
```

Yet it still shows the same thing

Comment: Please indicate the content of the response2 variable. You might have markdown syntax keywords (or should I say, characters) in your string (if it is a string)